# How to deploy a zip contains text files to remote repository from maven project

Tags: maven, maven-deploy-plugin

Is there any way to deploy a zip file which contains few text files to the remote repository from a maven project.

I tried to use maven-deploy plugin with goal as deploy-file, but the zip does not contain any pom.xml file.

Can anyone please share the way to upload a zip to a remote repository. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Create a zip file via maven-assembly-plugin and make a `mvn deploy` this should do the trick. Using maven-dependency-plugin is wrong. Or if you already have created the zip file an other way you can attach that zip file via [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/usage.html).

Comment: @khmarbaise We should really consider add zip type packaging which is open for years now.

Comment: If "remote repository" happens to be a non-maven repository and you can't use standard maven plugins for this, you can also check out the [wagon-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/wagon-maven-plugin/usage.html) which uses maven wagon modules to do the heavy-lifting.